# Cannot pass value to PHP Variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've been trying to pass value to php variable from javascript. I'm able to pass the data when the url from another php file, but I fail to get the data to be passed on the same page.

Here is the javascript code :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(document).on('click', '#getUser', function(e){    
        e.preventDefault();
        var uid = $(this).data('id'); // get id of clicked row

        $.ajax({
            url: 'user.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'id='+uid,
            success: function(data) {
    // the following will be executed when the request has been completed
                alert('Variable id has been sent successfully!');
              }
        })
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: what is the problem you have ? any error ?

Comment: `data: 'id='+uid,` need to be `data: {"id":uid},`

Comment: What did you try ? Is `user.php` the same page ? What's the name of the page that script lives in ?

Comment: what's the problem you are facing ?

Comment: console.log(uid) and check that data('id') is working... Sometimes it give me headache (the data('propiety'), should try var uid = $(this).attr('data-id'); // get id of clicked row

Comment: data: {id:uid},

Comment: Hamim Sairi  check the answers below and let us know problem solved or not?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `POST` type in your `ajax`.So

```
data: 'id='+uid,
```

need to be

```
data: {"id":uid}, //or you can do data: {id:uid},
```

And on your ***user.php*** page:-

```
<?php
echo $_POST['id'];//check what it outputs in your console
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `JSON` to your server, example:

instead of

```
data: 'id='+uid
```

use

```
data: {"id":uid}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is pseudo code to help you understand how can you pass parameters in an AJAX request:

```
var paramsToSend = {};
paramsToSend['data1'] = 'data1';
paramsToSend['data2'] = 'data2';

$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {params:JSON.stringify(paramsToSend)},
    ...
});
```

In your **users.php** you can:

```
$parameters = json_decode($_POST['params']
```

To convert them to array and have that array in $_POST, you can:

```
$_POST = (array) $parameters;
```